# How to track who is talking in discordjs/voice?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot that tells me when someone is talking. I can get my bot to join a Voice channel with a slash command, but I am having difficulties getting the bot to see who is talking. I have been looking at the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/voice/0.16.0/SpeakingMap:Class) and following the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html) up to this point

---

From my understanding, I would need to make an EventListner/EventEmitter for whenever the green bubble lights up. But I can't figure out how to at all. I saw some guides, [other](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discordjs/comments/jmvrf1/voiceconnection_speaking_event_not_working/) people [code](https://github.com/sillyfrog/discord.js-listenexample/blob/master/demo.js), and tried to BS the [SpeakingMap](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/speakingmap.html#on) methods, but I either get an error because I am not using TypeScript, if TS is the only way to run something like this, I will somehow switch my program from JS to TS...or I get an error saying stuff is undefined.

```
module.exports = {
    name: Events.VoiceStateUpdate,
    once: false,
    execute(newMember,oldMember) {
        if(newMember.member.user.id === clientId && thingname(oldMember.channel) !== null){
          console.log("I connected");
        }else{
            console.log("connected");
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I am able to get an event to go off when someone joins or leaves the channel. and I have it so it can go off when the bot joins. But I don't know what to do after this, SpeakingMap doesn't work, Noone has given any helpful information so far.
Thank you